# raw query with primary key

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

My model

```
class Despacho (models.Model):  
    bus=models.ForeignKey(Bus)  
    contador = models.IntegerField()
    cerrado = models.BooleanField(editable=False)

class Bus(models.Model):    
    numero_bus=models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    en_ruta = models.BooleanField(editable=False)
```

I need a query to extract the data which I save a bus, and I enter a
number of the bus and I need to know if there is a dispatch that
matches the search try to do the following query

my database is postgresql

```
d = Despacho.objects.raw('''SELECT * FROM operaciones_despacho WHERE operaciones_despacho.bus =  '%s' AND operaciones_despacho.cerrado = '%s'                                                    
;'''%(bus.numero_bus,False))
```

> error : column operaciones_despacho.bus does not exist

Comment: Why do you think you need to perform a raw query? And even worse, why do you think you need to perform it *incorrectly*?

Comment: I also would like to know why you need raw request?

Comment: What Ignacio is hinting at is that your code is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack. That's one of the big reasons to use the ORM over raw queries: it protects you again mistakes that may open up vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up in Django, we use raw sql only in the rare instances when it's particularly hard to write an ORM query. In this instance, writing an ORM query is much easier and shorter than a raw query.

```
Despacho.objects.filter(bus=bus).filter(cerrado=False)
```

On those rare instances when you need to do a raw query, take care you use the [params](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw) argument to raw instead of string formatting. The correct way to write your raw query is

```
Despacho.objects.raw('''SELECT * FROM operaciones_despacho WHERE operaciones_despacho.bus =  '%s' AND operaciones_despacho.cerrado = '%s'''' ,
 [bus.numero_bus,False])
```

But I emphasis once again that you should not be using a raw query here because it's a simple ORM query.